# Unable to clone from a repo from different user

Tags: git, mercurial

On my local, there are two user accounts.

1) User
   2) Hadoop

I mostly develop code on User and then copy in to hadoop to use it..

So instead of going this long route, i thought, maybe i can push the code to repo and
pull at other end

While I am able to push code from user to repo

But when i try to pull the code from hadoop.. I am getting this error?

```
remote: Permission denied (publickey).
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

Though, I am facing issues from mercurial, probably there might be some overlap among git users as well.. Hence tagging them but feel free to untag if someone thinks, the problem doesnt applies at their end.

Any clues?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's ssh telling you your hadoop user doesn't have access to the ssh server that your mercurial repo is sitting behind.  Whatever you did to set up a key for `user` do the same thing for `hadoop`.